# How do I send an array from Express Server to an AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, http, express

I have an AJAX request that is properly sent to the server and the server properly returns a response. However, as I am searching a database, the response looks like this:

```
[{name: 'example1'},
{name: 'example2'}]
```

However, when the response is passed to the client side javascript, it is a string created by the concatenation of the whole array, which is not great for me, as I need to iterate and access object keys. How can I pass and receive the data as an array?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: sounds like you are 99% of the way there. Starting from scratch would be a waste, you should provide what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before passing to the client side you should  convert it to valid json data by using

```
JSON.stringify(your_array)
```

after receiving on client side you must convert the json data let say my_json to valid javascript object by using

```
my_obj  = JSON.parse(my_json);
```

now you can perform all type of object's operation with my_obj;